# Entity Framework : Eager loading not working with string foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having trouble loading a child entity using eager loading, the eager loading works fine everywhere else in the project but its not working with any of the string foreign keys. My model is :

```
public class Listing : BaseAudit<int>
{
    public int? CommunityId { get; set; }
    public string LotId { get; set; }


    public Lot Lot { get; set; }
}

public class Lot : BaseAudit<string>
{
    public ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
}

public class BaseAudit<T> : BaseId<T>
{
    public BaseAudit()
    {
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
        Active = true;
    }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class BaseId<T> : BaseModel
{
    public T Id { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to load `Lot` property of `Listing` I have tried:

```
_db.Listings.Where(m => m.CommunityId == communityId && m.LotId != null).Include(a => a.Lot).ToList();
```

I have checked that it is generating correct SQL by using a break point but It is always returning with all `Lot` properties null. I can not figure out what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: The usual suspects: difference in leading spaces, case.

Comment: @GertArnold I checked that too, but if that was the case then the SQL generated would not give any results right. The SQL Generated gives the desired results but after `.ToList()` the child entity is null.

Comment: *The SQL Generated gives the desired results* If you mean that *it is generating correct SQL* (as you state in your question) than this isn't convincing enough. You should check whether the SQL query itself returns expected results.

Comment: It seems you tried to configure a one-to-many relationship between `Lots` and `Listings`: Every `Lot` has zero or more `Listings` and every `Listing` belongs to exactly one `Lot`. Am I Correct, or are there 'Lots` that don't belong to a `Listing'?

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Are you using EF6?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** `Listings` should be a virtual collection; `LotId` is never null, and `Include` should be immediately after your DbSet. And you should probably model your inheritance strategy

**Long answer**
It seems you tried to configure a one-to-many relationship between `Lots` and `Listings`: Every `Lot` has zero or more `Listings` and every `Listing` belongs to exactly one `Lot`.

For a proper one-to-many you should declare your collection of Listings virtual

```
public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
```

Because of the one-to-many relation, there is no `Listing` without a `Lot` Therefore the foreign key to Lot's primary key `LotId` is never null.

So you have a nullable int `communityId` (is that true? or is communityId an int?), and you want all `Listings` that have the same value for `Listing.CommunityId inclusive the one and only`Lot`this`Listing` has:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

List<Listing> result = dbContext.Listings
    .Include(listing => listing.Lot)
    .Where(listing => listing.communityId == communityId)
    .ToList();
```

If this doesn't help, then your use of inheritance might cause the problems. Relational databases don't know the concept of inheritance. You should tell entity framework using fluent API (or attributes) which inheritance strategy to model into tables. See [Inheritance Strategies](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Finally I see that some primary keys are int, and some primary keys are strings. Is that really intended? Is it useful?

Answer (score 0):

EF6 does not support `Include` with `Where` on related entities.

A possible workaround: [Entity Framework: Filtering Related Entity Collections](http://www.leftycoder.com/entity-framework-filtering-related-entity-collections/)

> As of Entity Framework 6, there isn’t a way to filter which related
>   entities are loaded when using .Include().